# How can i get current status or http code in django via request

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I check status code in  request.META but there is not available

Like

```
 request.status or request.status_code
```

Comment: It depends on the server code how you are returning.

Comment: What do you mean by get the status of `request`? Do note that if its the response code you are referring to like 2xx, 5xx then they are two different things here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's available on:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
....
HttpResponse.status_code
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get it using the following.

```
request.status_code
```